# How to remove file from a diffrent directory with PHP?

Tags: php, directory, unlink

I have a PHP file with `unlink()` in `application/views/delete/target.php` and I want to delete a file in `application/views/uploads/target.jpg`. When I call `target.php` I want to remove both `target.php` and `target.jpg` but so far I was only able to remove the target in the `delete/` folder.

```
<?php function destruct()
            { 
                unlink('../views/uploads/target.jpg');
                unlink('target.php');
            }
            destruct(); ?>
```

Comment: You need to go down one more directory, like this: `unlink('../../views/uploads/target.jpg');`, assuming you have permission to delete the file.

Comment: ../ is for one directorey so i always need to go one by one to the one that has the connection to the wanted one

Comment: Yes, I see that you could keep it simpler, like this: `unlink('../uploads/target.jpg');`

Comment: still thanks for help i'm  more of a noobie with php

Comment: I'm confused. You want `target.php` to delete itself?

Comment: I have build a cloud storage and now i have scrypt that creates as many php files  as there are uploads. 4uploads- 1d.txt 2d.xsdfs 3d.sdf 4d.blabla  and  it creates 4 1d.php 2d.php.... and when user calls /selects delete button in calls .php whitch deletes file and itself. Its a private cloud storage made for me and friends everyone can make their own invironment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php function destruct()
            { 
                unlink('../uploads/4d.jpg');
                unlink('4d.php');
            }
            destruct(); ?>
```

I just needed to go down by one folder and enter next one.